# what is the meaning of "bragging rights" in the following?

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of "bragging rights" in the following?
"They get a banner to hang in the gym and bragging rights over the surrounding towns."
thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bragging-rights?s=t

Answer (score 1):

It means they get not only a banner to hang in the gym but also an opportunity to speak proudly (brag) about their achievement. The surrounding towns don't have this right to brag because there is only one winner.